# Como visualizar documentos office en php?

Tags: php

Aquí esta contenido el código para la función

```
public function tipoArchivo($nombreArchivo, $extension) {
        $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
        $ruta = "../../Archivos/" . $id_usuario . "/" . $nombreArchivo;
        switch ($extension) {
            case 'pdf':
                return '<embed src="'.$ruta.'#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" />';
                break;
            case 'PDF':
                return '<embed src="'.$ruta.'#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" />';
                break;
            case 'docx':
                return '<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url='.$ruta.'&embedded=true" style="width:100%; height:100%;" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
                break;
        }
    }
```

Lo intente con el visualizador de documentos de Google y de office pero no los muestra.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes incluir el MIME type `header('Content-type: application/msword');`
que creo es ese, luego con `readfile( "ruta_al_archivo" );` deberia cargarlo de manera adecuada.

Comment: Disculpa me podrías indicar donde se debe incluir MIME type en el código de la función..